# MongoDB bind ip

Tags: mongodb

I want to allow specific IP addres to comunicate with the mongoDB that I have in  a server. In order to do that, I opened `mongod.conf` and edited as follows:

```
net : 
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost,<IpAdres>
security:
  authorization: enable
```

I tried with authorization `'enable'` but the only wait it works is as the initial configuration:

```
net : 
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost
#security:
# authorization: enable
```

Also If I set

```
net : 
  port: 27017, <IpAdress>
  bindIp: localhost
#security:
# authorization: enable
```

The error I got is:

`Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

My goal is to only allow a specific set of IP ADDRES to comunicate with the mongo on my server (comunicate = make consults)

**Version: 4.0.18** Running on RedHat 7.8

### netstat looks like this

`Proto | Recv-Q  |Send-Q | Local Address  | Foreign Address |  State | PID/Program name`

`tcp  |  0  | 0 |127.0.0.1:27017 |  0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN |  -`

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need enable authentication:

```
net:
 port: 27017
 bindIp: localhost, <YOUR_IP>
```

It is correct, probably you have another communication issue, check your ip/port allows traffic.

Command '***netstat -tulnp***' can help you.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Anyway, the error could be caused by other third reason, go to /run/mongodb folder and deleted the file called mongod.pid. Then try to restart the mongo using:

```
   sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: netstat looks like this 
-

`Proto | Recv-Q  |Send-Q | Local Address  | Foreign Address |  State | PID/Program name `
-

`tcp  |  0  | 0 |127.0.0.1:27017 |  0.0.0.0:* | LISTEN |  -  `

Comment: To bind to all IPv4 addresses, you can specify the bind ip address of 0.0.0.0. To bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you can specify the bind ip address of ::,0.0.0.0 or alternatively, use the new net.bindIpAll setting or the new command-line option --bind_ip_all.

Comment: Anyway documentation does not say nothing about [ ] chars and for me it does not work.

Comment: Bind all ip 4 and ip6 addres is well referred in docs, what he is asking is why if he bind 2 ips, write them in the right syntax, restart mongo gives error